# Bootstrap navbar dropdown glitch

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So, I just copied a code snippet for the navbar form from bootswatch and directly imported the required JQuery, bootstrap css and js files as you can see in the snippet below. It is being responsive when the browser is resized but when I click the button to get the dropdown menu of the navbar it glitches and doesn't go down and stay there but toggles back on its own.

No tweaks or changes has been made in the code and it works fine on the bootswatch website but it doesn't here. Can anyone explain why and give a fix?

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://bootswatch.com/4/united/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarColor02" aria-controls="navbarColor02" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation" style="">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarColor02">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
      <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" placeholder="Search" type="text">
      <button class="btn btn-secondary my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because `bootswatch` is using `bootstrap 4.0 beta` rather than `3`.and for `bootstrap4` you will need [popper.js](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.13.0/umd/popper.js)

see the demo below

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.13.0/umd/popper.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-primary">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarColor01" aria-controls="navbarColor01" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation" style="">
                  <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarColor01">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
      <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Search">
      <button class="btn btn-secondary my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</nav>
```

---

**EDIT**

While trying to include `popper.js` keep in mind to use only the `umd` specific directory, not `esm` or any other. See this previous [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47624287/why-isnt-this-bootstrap-carousel-slider-sliding/47624360#47624360) for details

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in the very thing you mentioned you changed; the Bootstrap and jQuery files. You're using the jQuery from Bootstrap 3.3.7, and the CSS from Bootstrap 4, which have conflicts. Also note that Bootstrap 4 additionally needs `Popper.js`.

Changing both Bootstrap files to use Bootstrap 4 (and including Popper) fixes this problem:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.6/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarColor02" aria-controls="navbarColor02" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation" style="">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarColor02">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
      <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" placeholder="Search" type="text">
      <button class="btn btn-secondary my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Hope this helps! :)